# Fullcalendar Save event to database not working on webserver

Tags: php, ajax

I have a full calendar that accepts events on drag and drop and saves them to the database using ajax and php.This works perfectly on localhost but does not work on a webserver.Is there something i need to change or add for this to work on the webserver?My Servers console log/error log shows no errors on my files.But the browser displays a javascript void(0); when i hover over the event on the calendar.But the table events does not update.It only seems to work on my localhost
Heres my fullcalendar code for add events:
JS

```
    eventReceive: function(event){
            var title = event.title;
            var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&zone='+zone,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    event.id = response.eventid;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.responseText);

                }
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
            console.log(event);
        },
```

And my process.php

```
<?php
include('rcon.php');
$type = $_POST['type'];

if($type == 'new')
{
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'].'+'.$_POST['zone'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO events (`title`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `allDay`) VALUES('$title','$startdate','$startdate','false')");
    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','eventid'=>$lastid));
}
?>
```

Database connection file:

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pwd','db');
?>
```

Comment: it looks like there is a undeclared variable $con which is likely declared in your include script. Are the database settings i.e. username/password/database correct for your webserver?

Comment: yes the database settings are correct

Comment: ive also opened the url to process.php and written an echo"test"; to check if i might be a permission issue but the file has no issues

Comment: from where variable zone in your ajax ? if it's not declare the ajax request can't run

Comment: This looks like you are using jQuery.  Is it included on your production server (or the CDN)?

Comment: @mohade variable zone is declared   var zone = "05:30";

Comment: @Sablefoste yes,jquery is included,but i  will check for any errors

Comment: on console my when i filter console to only display process.php,upon drop event is displays an empty array under post:[]